# Water level in a U-tube undergoing horizontal acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, fluid-statics

Here is the task:

> A U-tube, which is open on both sides and filled with water is undergoing constant horizontal acceleration. Knowing the acceleration $a$, and the distance between the 2 sides of the U-tube - $d$, calculate the difference in water levels in the 2 sides of the U-tube.

The answer at the end of my Physics book is $\frac{da}g$, but I don't really know how the pressure really changes across the U-tube or why the distance is so important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be conceptual.

> how the pressure really changes across the U-tube

[image: img]

Consider the liquid in the horizontal bar of the U-tube (shaded in the above picture). Now since that bar is accelerating to the right, there should be a net force on it. That force is provided by the pressure difference. Therefore pressure at A is greater than that of B. Pressure inside a liquid is dependent on the height of the liquid bar above that point. Thus the water level in the left bar increases while in the other bar decreases, to create this pressure difference.
(The same thing happens in an accelerating beaker)

Comment: Is there a way to measure the height difference?